# Selenium scraping elements

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Given a page is it possible to get all the hidden elements and also identify all the items that are dropdown(Jquery)?

I have already done with links easily  like this

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
```

I need to write 2 methods

1. Get all IWebElements that are Hidden
2. Get IWebElements that are jQueryDropdown.

Any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: It will be easier to understand if you provide sample html with what exactly you are looking for

Comment: I don t have the html page as its work stuff.but i thought in this scenario would be self explanatory. I need to find all the hidden elements in a page and then I need to print their name-Id .

Comment: Hiden element would be those where element.isDisplayed() is false. I dont know how to get Dropdowm elements without the html

Comment: @Morvader I should have thought about IsDisplayed.Thanks.